# mocking / patching external API call in python for unit-testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I'm implementing unit testing for a django handler. I have been trying to mock/patch the api connection instance but keep getting the error:

```
super(MTurkConnection, self).__init__(aws_access_key_id,
TypeError: must be type, not MagicMock
```

My test code looks like this and is living in tests/test_mturk_handler.py:

```
class Mocked_Connection(MTurkConnection):
  pass

@patch('mturk.handlers.MTurkHandler.boto.mturk.connection.MTurkConnection')
def test_can_pull_data(self, mock_api):
  mock_api.return_value = Mocked_Connection()
  response = self.client.post(reverse('mechanical'), self.data)
  self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The API call is beign made in this section of code and is living in handlers/MTurkHandler.py:

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
import boto
...
if serializer.is_valid():
  # instantianting connection
  mturk_connection = MTurkConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, host=HOST)
```

I have tried several return values but I keep getting the same error. Any ideas what's the right way to do it??

Comment: To me, it looks like you can just patch `mturk.handlers.MTurkHandler.MTurkConnection`...